# Continuous Transformation of $u$-Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

$u$-substitution tells us that
$$
   \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^2\cos x\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}u^2\,du = \frac{1}{3},
$$
where we made the substitution $u(x) = \sin x$, and $u(0)=0$, $u(\pi/2)=1$.

What I want to do is visualize a continuous transformation from one system of variables to the other,
$$
   u_t(x) = (1-t)\sin x +t x, \quad 0\leq t \leq 1,
$$
where $u_0(x) = \sin x$, $u_1(x) = x$, and
$$
   \int_{a_t}^{b_t} (u_t(x))^2 u'_t(x) \,dx = \frac{1}{3}, \quad 
 0\leq t \leq 1.
$$
The only trouble I'm having is figuring out what the bounds of the integrals should be, as a function of $t$. Obviously $a_0 = 0$, $b_0 =\pi/2$, and $a_1 = 0$, $b_1=1$, but I'm getting confused when $t$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Does what I'm looking for make sense? I've always thought of $u$-substitution (or change-of-variables) as changing one integral into the other by "stretching" or "deforming" the area under the graph. So naturally I though it should be possible to make that deformation explicit. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $$\int_{a_t}^{b_t} (u_t(x))^2   u'_t(x) \,dx = \frac {(u_t(x))^3}{3}\bigg|_{a_t}^{b_t} = \frac{1}{3}, \quad 
 0\leq t \leq 1.$$Thus you have to have $$(u_t(b_t))^3 -(u_t(a_t))^3=1$$